# Why is a pointer used to access shared memory?

Tags: c, parallel-processing

I have seen a lot of parallel programming code like finding the maximum of array, matrix multiplication, etc. use pointers. I don't understand why it is used. Example:`(shseg+(offset*sizeof(float))) = sum;`

The code for matrix multiplication:

```
shseg = shmat(handle,NULL,0);
for(row=SIZE/2;row<SIZE;row++){

  for(column=0;column<SIZE;column++){
    sum = 0;

    for(tindex=0;tindex<SIZE;tindex++){ 
      sum+=a[row][tindex]*b[tindex][column];
    }

    *(shseg+(offset*sizeof(float))) = sum;
    offset++;
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain why a pointer is used?

Comment: What is not understandable for you?

Comment: You are addressing a point in memory... What else would seem appropriate to you?

Comment: i have seen that in many code this type of thing if(pid==fork()){}else{*(shseg....)} .i need to know why pointer is used before (shseg).what is actual logical reason?

Comment: if i am writing this line shseg = shmat(handle,NULL,0); ,then what size of memory chunk is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the example you show uses shared memory API, which provides you a flat chunk of memory, not an array of, say, floats. Therefore, you need to do all your pointer manipulations manually.

You could also cast your shared pointer to `float*` and use an index, like this:

```
shseg = shmat(handle,NULL,0);
float *fshseg = (float*)shseg;

...

fshseg[index++] = sum;
```

Comment: @prjndhi `shmat` returns `void*`.

Comment: There's no need to cast a `void *` to a different (data) pointer, in C.

Comment: @unwind This is certainly true. I prefer doing it anyway, to make the fact that the type gets changed be more visible to the readers of my code.

Comment: @prjndhi null pointer does not need a cast; this is a void pointer, which also does not need a cast to assign to pointers of other types. But adding a cast does not hurt the compile, and IMO improves readability.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that means void* behave like generic pointer .

Comment: if i am writing this line shseg = shmat(handle,NULL,0); ,then what size of memory chunk is created?

Comment: @prjndhi `shmat` attaches to shared memory created elsewhere, so the size is the same as what's been passed to `shmget`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have an allocated space of memory which is been shared with your program, you will be going all the way through the memory, if you didn't used a pointer you would not be able the get the memory address value, thats why you need to use it.

Comment: if i am writing this line  shseg = shmat(handle,NULL,0); ,then what size of memory chunk is created?